# PHP Table Creation (Multidimensional Arrays)

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have 4 arrays the first being the table headings for which there are six:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> string(3) "Who",
    [1]=> string(4) "What",
    [2]=> string(4) "When",
    [3]=> string(5) "Where",
    [4]=> string(3) "Why",
    [5]=> string(3) "How"
}
```

and 3 other arrays that contain coinciding values. What I want to do is take the values of the first array is to make them the keys of another array with a value or `array` like so:

```
array(6) {
    ["Who"]=> array(0) {},
    ["What"]=> array(0) {},
    ["When"]=> array(0) {},
    ["Where"]=> array(0) {},
    ["Why"]=> array(0) {},
    ["How"]=> array(0) {}
}
```

and then populate those arrays with the coinciding values much like a table. An example of one of the other arrays would be:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> string(3) "red",
    [1]=> string(4) "blue",
    [2]=> string(4) "green",
    [3]=> string(6) "yellow",
    [4]=> string(3) "black",
    [5]=> string(3) "white"
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I am going to say that all 3 arrays have the exact same value as the one above.

In the end I want the resulting array to be:

```
array(6) {
    ["Who"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(3) "red",
        [1]=> string(3) "red",
        [2]=> string(3) "red"
    },
    ["What"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(4) "blue",
        [1]=> string(4) "blue",
        [2]=> string(4) "blue"
    },
    ["When"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(5) "green",
        [1]=> string(5) "green",
        [2]=> string(5) "green"
    },
    ["Where"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(6) "yellow",
        [1]=> string(6) "yellow",
        [2]=> string(6) "yellow"
    },
    ["Why"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(5) "black",
        [1]=> string(5) "black",
        [2]=> string(5) "black"
    },
    ["How"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(5) "white",
        [1]=> string(5) "white",
        [2]=> string(5) "white"
    }
}
```

The code I am currently working with is as follows:

```
... //Tokens are generated above (this is all in a loop)
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $table[$token] = array();
    } else {
        foreach ($table as $col) {
            $table[$col][$i] = $token;
        }
    }
}
$i = $i + 1;
```

All this generates is `array(0) {}`

It'd be appreciated if someone could point out a flaw in my logic.

EDIT:

Here is what the table will look like:

```
_________________________________________
| Who | What | When | Where | Why | How |
-----------------------------------------
| red | blue | green| yellow|black|white|
-----------------------------------------
| red | blue | green| yellow|black|white|
-----------------------------------------
| red | blue | green| yellow|black|white|
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sort of come to a conclusion for your problem and it's shown below:

*This is just to build the arrays similar to yours*

```
$one = array(
        0 => 'Who',
        1 => 'What',
        2 => 'When',
        3 => 'Where',
        4 => 'Why',
        5 => 'How'
    );



    $der = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $array = array(
            0 => 'red',
            1 => 'blue',
            2 => 'green',
            3 => 'yellow',
            4 => 'black',
            5 => 'white'
        );
        array_push($der, $array);
    }
```

I've basically created a multidimensional array(`$der`) instead of the 3 seperate arrays of values that you have to complete this task.

You can do the same with the use of [**`array_push()`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-push.php) to create the new array.

Now we need to loop through our `$der` array while retaining the keys (table headings) from the `$one` array.

```
    $new = array();
    foreach($der as $item) {

        foreach($item as $key => $val) {
            $new[$one[$key]][] = $val;
        }

    }
```

Where a `print_r($new)` warrants a return of:

```
Array
(
    [Who] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [1] => red
            [2] => red
        )

    [What] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => blue
            [2] => blue
        )

    [When] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => green
            [2] => green
        )

    [Where] => Array
        (
            [0] => yellow
            [1] => yellow
            [2] => yellow
        )

    [Why] => Array
        (
            [0] => black
            [1] => black
            [2] => black
        )

    [How] => Array
        (
            [0] => white
            [1] => white
            [2] => white
        )

)
```

As you can see in the loop, we reference the `$one[$key]` where `$key` is the current index of the array item that you're iterating through.

---

### Alternatively

You could do something like this (**NOTE**: *The `$one` below is the same as the `$one` above*):

```
$values = array();
foreach ($der as $item) {

    foreach ($item as $key => $val) {
        $values[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
```

Now harnessing [**`array_combine()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) you could simply do:

```
$new = array_combine($one, $values);
```

Which will warrant the same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

try array_fill_keys() function

```
$tokens= array('Who', 'What', 'When', 'Where', 'Why', 'How');
$table = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow','black', 'white');
$a = array_fill_keys($tokens, $table);
print_r($a);
```